# Prevent inheriting validation attributes in model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, inheritance, validationattribute

I'm using a base contact model which other custom contact models classes inherit.

```
public class BaseContactModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Firstname is required")]
    public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

The base contact model uses validation attributes to flag a property is required but in some cases I want to override or stop that.  Is this going to be possible?

```
public class ContactModel : BaseContactModel
{
    [NotRequired]
    public override string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

I attempted to use a new validation attribute **NotRequired** to just return true, but appears the attributes are just being stacked up so Required & NotRequired are running and the validation is failing.

On looking for solutions (which I couldn't find) I found that some unrelated attributes have an 'inherited' property, but I don't see this in the native validation attributes in **System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations**.

Is this a lost cause? Do I need to roll my own versions which would support disabling inheritance? Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this below, I've created one class `Model` that inherits from another `BaseModel`, used the new keyword then validated one of each instance.  From what I can see, they both use the base attributes.

I've added a control class `ControlModel` for clarity on the validation routine.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ValidationTest<Model>();
        ValidationTest<BaseModel>();
        ValidationTest<ControlModel>();

        Console.Read();
    }

    private static void WriteAttributeInfo<T>()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Concat(typeof(T), " attributes:"));
        typeof(T).GetProperties().SelectMany(m => m.GetCustomAttributes(true)).Select(a => { Console.WriteLine(a); return a; }).ToList();
    }

    private static void ValidationTest<T>()
    {
        object obj = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
        Console.WriteLine(string.Concat(typeof(T), " test: isValid = ", Validator.TryValidateObject(obj, new ValidationContext(obj, serviceProvider: null, items: null), new List<ValidationResult>())));
    }
}

class ControlModel
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }
}

class BaseModel
{
    [RequiredAttribute]
    public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }

    [RequiredAttribute]
    public virtual string Email { get; set; }
}

class Model : BaseModel
{
    public new string FirstName { get; set; }

    public new string Email { get; set; }
}
```

ConsoleApplication1.Model test: **isValid = False**

ConsoleApplication1.BaseModel test: **isValid = False**

ConsoleApplication1.ControlModel test: **isValid = True**

From this example, it appears you can't override/hide/ignore inherited required validation (haven't tried others yet) attributes.

Comment: I hate answering and accepting my own questions but from the test above, it seems like what the original question asked for, cannot be done.

Comment: Is it really no solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

This may be the case where you actually want a new property

```
 public class ContactModel : BaseContactModel 
{
        [NotRequired]
        public new string FirstName { get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: Does this replace the attributes? I've tried using new (with a virtual property) but it still seems to be hitting the validation.

Comment: I've used this strategy a few times in the past.  It should be a brand new property, therefore only one validation attribute or the other should fire.  Of course it depends how you declare or use your model variable to determine which property is actually used.  If it is not working, you may want to post some controller code to see if we can figure out why.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'll have another effort this evening and may possibly even try on a site straight out the box.

Comment: See below answer and example - from this, it doesn't look like it's going to play ball :(